# Ipython/Jupyter: Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am using python 2.7 through ipython and anaconda. I've restarted my computer, tried different notebooks and tried updating stuff through the conda command line. Yet every time I try to open a notebook the kernel times out and that seems to crash the notebook. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Update: After restarting the kernel from within the notebook the terminal gave this message:

```
[E 17:45:18.308 NotebookApp] Exception restarting kernel
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\bidby\Anaconda\lib\site- packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 88, in post
    yield gen.maybe_future(km.restart_kernel(kernel_id))
  File "C:\Users\bidby\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 870, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\bidby\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line
 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
TimeoutError: Timeout waiting for restart
[E 17:45:18.308 NotebookApp] {
  "Origin": "http://localhost:8888",
  "Content-Length": "0",
  "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "Host": "localhost:8888",
  "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHT
ML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36",
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/The%20Prodge/For%20bidby
/SVC-CycleAverages-New-Copy2.ipynb"
}
[E 17:45:18.308 NotebookApp] 500 POST /api/kernels/8df55a56-0cb9-431c-8034-db6c1
6fee7ba/restart (::1) 31152.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop
/The%20Prodge/For%20bidby/SVC-CycleAverages-New-Copy2.ipynb
[I 17:45:19.460 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: 8df55a56-0cb9-431c-8034-db6c16fee7ba
```

Also the notebook gives this:

The kernel has died, and the automatic restart has failed. It is possible the kernel cannot be restarted. If you are not able to restart the kernel, you will still be able to save the notebook, but running code will no longer work until the notebook is reopened.

When I close and reopen the notebook the terminal says this:

```
[I 17:46:17.394 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/The Prodge/For bidby/SVC-CycleAverages-New-Copy2.ipynb
[W 17:46:17.398 NotebookApp] Saving untrusted notebook Desktop/The Prodge/For bidby/SVC-CycleAverages-New-Copy2.ipynb
[W 18:01:59.888 NotebookApp] Session not found: session_id=u'1768b420-e3ba-4f69-a392-d476b76a5774'
[W 18:01:59.905 NotebookApp] 404 DELETE /api/sessions/1768b420-e3ba-4f69-a392-d476b76a5774 (::1) 17.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/The%20Prodge/For%20bidby/SVC-CycleAverages-New-Copy2.ipynb
[I 18:02:00.019 NotebookApp] Kernel started: a7d04bdf-d0c8-4b53-be62-3344c6b0f453
[W 18:02:10.052 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from a7d04bdf-d0c8-4b53-be62-3344c6b0f453
[W 18:03:28.661 NotebookApp] Notebook Desktop/The Prodge/For bidby/SVC-CycleAverages-New-Copy2.ipynb is not trusted
[W 18:03:28.815 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20160405174149 (::1) 12.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/The%20Prodge/For%20bidby/SVC-CycleAverages-New-Copy2.ipynb
[I 18:05:34.392 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/The Prodge/For bidby/SVC-CycleAverages-New-Copy2.ipynb
[W 18:05:34.395 NotebookApp] Saving untrusted notebook Desktop/The Prodge/For bidby/SVC-CycleAverages-New-Copy2.ipynb
```

Comment: Is there any error message in the terminal where you started the notebook?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was fixed by deactivating the antivirus (AVG). This is probably a security issue...

To replicate the problem I reinstalled Anaconda2-4.0.0-Windows-x86_64 and I got the same error with AVG activated.

Kind regards 
Adrian